# arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-gcc: erreur: unrecognized command line option ‘-mno-tls-direct-seg-refs’

Tags: buildroot

I tried to use the defconfig of raspberrypi2 of buildroot then I run the command make.Until now all things are good,but when I added some target packages then I run make I got this error:

```
arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-gcc: erreur: unrecognized command line option ‘-mno-tls-direct-seg-refs’
```

this link contain all the messages that I got on my console:http://pastebin.com/mgVthm8z

Comment: Please report this to BR's mailing list. Btw. have you tried external toolchain, i.e. Linaro or something else?

Answer (score 0):

The `-mno-tls-direct-seg-refs` option is a x86 specific option, that libselinux is trying to use with an ARM toolchain. Which obviously cannot work. Seems like a bug in the libselinux package. As Yegor said, please report this to the Buildroot mailing list or bug tracker.

Answer (score -1):

I got this:

The Makefile of libselinux performs the following check:

> ARCH := $(patsubst i%86,i386,$(shell uname -m))
>   ifneq (,$(filter i386,$(ARCH)))
>   TLSFLAGS += -mno-tls-direct-seg-refs
>   endif
>
> Which means that if the host machine is an x86, then TLSFLAGS will
>   contain -mno-tls-direct-seg-refs. That command line option causes
>   libselinux to fail when building it for target architectures where the
>   compiler doesn't support that option, i.e. MIPS:
>
> mips-img-linux-gnu-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option
>   ‘-mno-tls-direct-seg-refs’
>
> So to fix that problem we can set the ARCH variable to $(KERNEL_ARCH),
>   and then append it to the LIBSELINUX_MAKE_OPTS.
>
> Signed-off-by: Vicente Olivert Riera

link: https://patchwork.ozlabs.org/patch/518324/